# ModX getResource stopped working

Tags: mysql, sql, modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I can't get a result with getResource anymore.

For example, I want to query my blog posts:
My articles are created with the Articles plugin.

In my template, I have:

```
[[!getResources:ifempty=`No Resource`? &parents=`33` &showHidden=`1` ]]
```

It simply shows "No Resource".
Without the ifempty tag, it simply doesn't show anything.

The weird thing is I know I have those articles in my database. When I try with the parameter `debug=true`, I see the article objects' dump in place of the template. So the query is working fine, getResource retrieves the articles when debug is set to true!

With debug, I can see the SQL query in my log file:

> [2014-02-10 16:58:37] (ERROR @ /huayang/index.php) context for 33 is
>   web
>       [2014-02-10 16:58:37] (ERROR @ /huayang/index.php) SELECT `modResource`.`id`, `modResource`.`type`, `modResource`.`contentType`,
>   `modResource`.`pagetitle`, `modResource`.`longtitle`,
>   `modResource`.`description`, `modResource`.`alias`,
>   `modResource`.`link_attributes`, `modResource`.`published`,
>   `modResource`.`pub_date`, `modResource`.`unpub_date`,
>   `modResource`.`parent`, `modResource`.`isfolder`,
>   `modResource`.`introtext`, `modResource`.`richtext`,
>   `modResource`.`template`, `modResource`.`menuindex`,
>   `modResource`.`searchable`, `modResource`.`cacheable`,
>   `modResource`.`createdby`, `modResource`.`createdon`,
>   `modResource`.`editedby`, `modResource`.`editedon`,
>   `modResource`.`deleted`, `modResource`.`deletedon`,
>   `modResource`.`deletedby`, `modResource`.`publishedon`,
>   `modResource`.`publishedby`, `modResource`.`menutitle`,
>   `modResource`.`donthit`, `modResource`.`privateweb`,
>   `modResource`.`privatemgr`, `modResource`.`content_dispo`,
>   `modResource`.`hidemenu`, `modResource`.`class_key`,
>   `modResource`.`context_key`, `modResource`.`content_type`,
>   `modResource`.`uri`, `modResource`.`uri_override`,
>   `modResource`.`hide_children_in_tree`, `modResource`.`show_in_tree`,
>   `modResource`.`properties` FROM `modx_site_content` AS `modResource`
>   WHERE  ( modResource.parent IN (33,34,35,36) AND
>   `modResource`.`deleted` = 0 AND `modResource`.`published` = 1 )  ORDER
>   BY publishedon DESC LIMIT 5

When I run this query directly in phpmyadmin, I get the articles!

To be clear, getResource simply won't work whatever the query I try to make, if debug isn't set to true. It won't show my any error at any point..

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.

So.. any idea how I can fix this? Any suggestion how I should proceed to debug this?

Edit: getresources-1.6.1-pl

Edit2:

Started debugging, snippet.getresources.php, line 430

```
$collection = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $criteria, $dbCacheFlag);
```

$collection is an empt array..
$criteria is a xPDOQuery_mysql Object which looks correct..

I'm gonna sleep through this and will reinstall ModX tomorrow if I can't fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my template was in Templates instead of Chunks, the snippet started working again after I moved articlePreview into Chunks.

Some kind of output would have helped..

Hope this can help someone.